# How to enable Yarn for Jenkinsfile Pipeline syntax?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, yarnpkg

Trying to set up a simple unit test runner with Jenkins 2 using a Jenkinsfile and Pipeline declarative syntax. The below sample just about works, but I'd like to use `yarn` instead of `npm`.

**Jenkinsfile**

```
#!groovy

pipeline {
  agent any

  tools {nodejs 'node-8.10.0'} // previously configured via Manage Jenkins -> Global Tool Configuration

  stages {
    stage('Unit') {
      steps {
        checkout scm
        sh 'node -v' // 8.10.0
        sh 'npm -v' // 5.6.0
        sh 'npm install' // <-- desired change: 'yarn install'
        sh 'npm run test:unit' // <-- desired change: 'yarn test:unit'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Bonus question: is `checkout scm` really required? Adding it appears to cause it to run twice.

Answer (score 13):

You can set `yarn` as a installable dependency in the node tool configuration:
[image]

After defining the **NodeJS** tool, you can declare which global packages you want to install.

You will find it in the *Global Tool Configuration* menu in the *Manage Jenkins* section.

Each time your pipeline's is builded, the tool will provide a **NodeJS** environment with *yarn* installed.

Answer (score 4):

There is no yarn plugin for Jenkins as far as I know. So there is no yarn tool which can be easily used in a Pipeline and will take care of the yarn installation.

So here are some other possibilities:

You can install yarn locally on Jenkins and use `sh 'yarn install'` in the pipeline. See https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install#alternatives-stable for a list of possible options how to install it. Some steps can easily be scripted in a pipeline like the `curl` solution.

Or you can install yarn via the npm provided in the pipeline:

```
sh "npm install -g yarn"
sh "yarn install"
```

Or if you are using Java and Maven you can use the [frontend-maven-plugin](https://github.com/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin)
to install yarn via Maven (which has a tool blog in pipelines) and then use the installed yarn by this plugin.

Build inside a docker container the node container has yarn already installed

```
pipeline {
agent {
    docker { image 'node:8.11' }
}
stages {
    stage('Test') {
        steps {
            sh 'yarn install'
        }
    }
}
```

}

And like you observed the checkout is redundant. A declarative pipeline will check out the code and the Pipeline script in a special pre step before your steps.