# Runing a command on a local folder with Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, yarnpkg

I have this folder structure:

- /home/user/project

  - common
  - web
  - mobile

I would like to run `yarn test` in every on this folders in parallel and I would like to use Jenkins (or something else?) to have an easy to use user interface

is it possible ?

I use the `nodeJS` plugin in a freestyle project.
I install nodejs like this :
[image]
Then I try to do this :
[image]
then I have this error:
[image]

Looks like yarn is not installed... but it should be installed because I put yarn as a global packages

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that the issue you're encountering may be related to a specific problem discussed in this Stack Overflow post: ***[How to enable Yarn for Jenkinsfile Pipeline syntax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51531027/how-to-enable-yarn-for-jenkinsfile-pipeline-syntax)***

Based on my assessment, the error you're facing appears to be associated with Yarn not being configured as an environment variable within your Jenkins setup, which could result in it not being injected correctly during job execution (in my opinion).

To address this, I recommend considering the use of the **NPM and Yarn Wrapper and Steps plugin**. It's a straightforward solution, check all the details at ***https://plugins.jenkins.io/npm-yarn-wrapper-steps/*** to configure and could potentially resolve the issue you're facing. I encourage you to give it a try to see if it aligns with your requirements. The plus is that you can use on a GUI Job or pipeline (best solution for me).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run the command across three folders in parallel, it makes more sense to create a declarative pipeline and use the `parallel` command [docs](https://www.jenkins.io/blog/2017/09/25/declarative-1/). Your code would look like this:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Run Tests') {
            parallel {
                stage('Common') {
                    steps {
                        dir(/home/user/project/common) {
                            sh "yarn test"  
                        }
                    }
                }
                stage('web') {
                    steps {
                        dir(/home/user/project/web) {
                            sh "yarn test"  
                        }
                    }
                }
                stage('mobile') {
                    steps {
                        dir(/home/user/project/mobile) {
                            sh "yarn test"  
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This will trigger `yarn test` across all three directories at once. As for the installation, just make sure you have nodeJs and yarn installed on your Jenkins machine and it should work without having to use plugins.